# Humans returning to tribalism

Tags: science-based, society, humans

I'm working on setting in which a prison ship crashes on an unexplored/unknown planet, and due to infighting and environmental factors the prisoners return to tribalism at best or feral animals at worse.

What I'm wondering is if this is realistic or even possible.

How many generations would this take? I've read a bit about feral children, but a lot I find about them seems like conjecture and not to mention that they were completely isolated.

Comment: From your question I understand that *you do not want conjecture*. Do you understand that most of the answers on this site are based on conjecture?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that I truely understood the meaning of the word conjecture. I thought it meant completely fabricated and without any baisis where as that's not the case. I'm completely fine with conjecture. Sorry again!

Comment: Humans *returning* to tribalism? When exactly have we left tribalism behind us? *"According to such studies, then, "tribalism" is in some sense an inescapable fact of human neurology simply because many human brains are not adapted to working with large populations."* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribalism))

Comment: *"tribalism at best or feral animals at worse."* Have you ever been to a football game?

Comment: `What I'm wondering is if this is realistic or even possible. ` It depends. If they have a solar-powered cellphone that can access Twitter over a satellite link, I would not rule that out.

Comment: @AlexP "*When exactly have we left tribalism behind us?*" This can't be more true.  Racism, religion, **identity politics**, street gangs, multiculturalism, etc *ad nauseam*.  The only difference between success, relatively integrated First World societies and Third World dumps like Afghanistan and Somalia are the expansiveness of the tribes.

Comment: I came here to make a comment about tribalism still existing everywhere you look, but seems I've been beaten to it. So I've just given all the comments above a +1.

Comment: "How many generations" - we have to assume this was not a single gender prison ship, and there was sufficient number of people of both sexes to establish a population?

Comment: Having read _Lord of the Flies_, I'd have no difficulty believing the survivors 'reverting' to tribalism within weeks

Comment: They are prison inmates. That means many of them *have lived in tribes for most of their lives already!* Because street gangs are basically tribes. It is the most basic form of organisation that springs up anywhere there is lack of general policing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this realistic, yes, definitely... Would they survive long term... Unlikely.

For the sake of this answer I'm going to assume that there is at least 50% females in the survivors as anything less and the chances shrink exponentially. I'll also assume they crashed into a temperate/tropical zone of a planet similar to Earth.

**Lawlessness**

Any time there is a breakdown in society, or large scale mistrust of government etc, then riots ensue. Groups band together and go about doing whatever they want to do. The size of these groups is often down to how easily they can co-ordinate and their purpose can be anything from general aggression to violent looting.

Even so there is often a small group of people in the middle of these mobs, they run the show, they decide what they are going to do and others follow, the Pack Alpha if you will.

**Prisons**

Most of my information comes from documentaries, I thankfully don't have real life experience in a prison, and those same documentaries often look at maximum security prisons in the US, but...

There are usually groups within those prisons that band together, often race is used as the identifier for which group they fit into. But again there is often a leader figure within these groups, a person or two that run the show, they look after the group and decide how to react to certain situations.

**Tribalism**

Tribalism is a fairly broad term, but taken from wikipedia:

> The word "tribe" can be defined to mean an extended kin group or clan with a common ancestor, or can also be described as a group with shared interests, lifestyles and habits. The proverb "birds of a feather flock together" describes homophily, the human tendency to form friendship networks with people of similar occupations, interests, habits. Some tribes can be located in geographically proximate areas, like villages or bands,

So by this it's not quite right to use the term in reference to prisons or rioters. But if we consider that the term above: homophily, then that is exactly what prisons and rioters act like, banding together for a common purpose.

If we consider that any group of stranded prisoners would be exactly like this then you could argue that they would form a tribe immediately, in fact the prison ship itself may already have had several on board.

**Survivability**

Now, groups of people in a disaster such as a shipwrecks don't wash ashore and think... *"well, that was bad, better start planting some crops because I'll be here a while"*.

So these groups that would most likely already distrust each other would quickly bind together to deal with one group in particular... the guards. They wouldn't necessarily kill the guards, maybe they would incorporate them into the group, maybe exile them, its up to you as the writer, but they would need to be dealt with in some way.

After that however a few simple questions need to be asked:

- Would they start collecting seeds of tasty local fruit... *unlikely*
- Would a prison ship carry a stock of seeds ripe for germination and planting... *unlikely*
- Would they eat every bit of familiar food found in the wreck along with all the readily available food surrounding it... *VERY LIKELY*

So these groups could all band together or split apart, there would certainly be a struggle for leadership, but whether its one or many groups is up to you.

**So considering this: would they actually survive long term?**

Short answer... probably not, if there was a large scale confrontation then many lives would be lost either to being killed or from disease as a result of injuries sustained during fights. So if that conflict happened then probably only one group would remain, and assuming that the leadership of it survived then they would turn nomadic, moving around the region, hunting and gathering food.

If more than one group survived then they'd go separate ways and eventually meet again and probably have another fight over the local food.

However they would need to last long enough that mate and raise their off spring, true tribalism is up in the air as to exactly what it means but if we take the above wiki argument as a guide where all of the tribe would be related to each other then it would take several generations to do this.

While nomadic groups could survive long term:

Would these people have enough skills to do so?

Would they attempt to settle and begin farming?

How many died from Local Predators (presumably not the invisible hunter type)

How many die from eating poisonous food?

How many die from bacteria infections due to being on an unknown planet with bacteria their bodies have never encountered before so would have no immune response to?

All of this is up to you as the writer.

**TL:DR**

Clan group type tribes yes plausible, long term survival into true tribalism probably not

Comment: I agree, though I also suspect that the sheer number of survivors would also be a significant factor for many reasons, and increasing that number would also increase their long term survival likelihood

Comment: @Dalila, i agree, however increasing the number of initial survivors also increases the speed at which local resources in terms of food would be completely used up, which actually decreases the survival rate in total, it also increases the liklihood of conflicts between factions (more voices usually results in more opposition rather than more cohesion), only those groups forward thinking and knowledgeable enough to begin farming or at least long term planning would benefit from the increased numbers

Answer (score 19):

Becoming feral animals is not realistic. Aeons ago, primates found an ecological niche in form of society building and use of technology. They evolved to specialize in this niche. We had weapons, so our claws became tiny and brittle. Our teeth and digestive tracts degenerated because we had fire to make our food easier to chew and digest. The only thing which got bigger and bigger were our brains which in turn consumed more and more calories and oxygen.

Modern humans are physically unprepared to return to a feral state. It would take hundreds of generations of harsh natural selection to regain the necessary traits. They would not survive without forming a society. And when they have a society, they no longer have any evolutionary pressure to become feral.

Returning to a stone-age society, on the other hand, is quite likely. Modern humans did not yet evolve very far from this lifestyle. You could in fact argue that we are still more optimized for a stone-age lifestyle than a modern lifestyle. Our skeletons did not evolve for sitting all day, so we get chronic back pain. Our feeding instincts did not evolve for an environment with unlimited food supply, so we become obese. So if the circumstances would require a group of humans to abandon all their technology, they could return to a stone-age society immediately. They might need some time to acquire the necessary practical skills (how do you start a fire without matches? How do you hunt an animal without guns?) but [there are books for that](https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=sr_aj?node=864488&ajr=0).

So if the library of the prison ship has any literature about survival, or anyone on board happend to be a boyscout or survivalist, then forming a tribal stone-age society would happen almost immediately. If there is infighting within the group (quite likely, because you are talking about prision inmates), then it is quite likely that they would soon fracture into individual groups which then over several generations might develop into warring tribes and eventually warring cultures.

Comment: Research indicates that sitting is perfectly natural.  The problem instead is, the design of our chairs. https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2018/09/24/649169060/cant-get-comfortable-in-your-chair-heres-what-you-can-do

Comment: Can you please cite your claim that "We had textiles, so we lost our fur"? Chronologically, I believe it is in exactly the opposite order.

Comment: @ubadub Do you consider animal skin as textiles?

Comment: @ubadub OK, found [an article which says that humans lost their fur before they developed technology](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/08/19/science/why-humans-and-their-fur-parted-ways.html). I edited the answer.

Comment: @Philipp you really should do research before making bold claims. I would also dispute that "We had weapons, so our claws became tiny and brittle." Primates, other than lemurs, don't really have claws in the first place.

Comment: Primates have nails, and perhaps not due to something as audacious as "making weapons", it was selected against the claws that primate's ancestors had. It's hard to think nails have a positive trait for anything other than the dexterity associated with it. We did evolve with cooked meat, and modern humans will be tough to find their caloric needs without fire - they could though, they'd just need to eat more. Diseases are quite rare when high populations aren't there to fester it so there wouldn't be a safety issue with raw meat. Animals from pastures and not factories make good tartare.

Answer (score 12):

The people involved in the [Bounty Mutiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutiny_on_the_Bounty) were able to settle into a tribal culture at generation 0, and just used help from indigenous for better settling.

True, a lot of them were killed during subsequent interactions with locals, but I think that is kind of normal for that environment (see also Melville's Typee).

Consider that a complex social organization requires dedicated people, and dedicating people to non resource harvesting task can only be done when there is surplus production. I don't think that hunter-gatherers can rely on surplus resources, and establishing agriculture on an unknown planet is going to take some generations at least.

So I would say that also in your case is perfectly realistic to expect a tribal organization from day 0, when the group starts struggling for surviving.

Comment: There weren't any natives; there were two distinct groups in the mutineer group, one Polynesians and the other European transportees. Apparently the two groups fought each other for a number of years and halved the total number of islanders.

Answer (score 2):

These are not normal people, they're criminals. Low education, low morals and low self discipline in general. Most would be unable to survive if not organised and disciplined.

They're not even normal criminals, these are maximum security inmates, you don't lock up jaywalkers on a prison ship. This [link](https://www.providr.com/most-dangerous-prisoners-in-the-world/) will give you an idea of some of the sorts of people you would have. I would not even want to sleep in their vicinity and if any looked at me sideways I'd take it as a death threat. Maximum dehumanises both inmates and guards over time. The majority are not so bad, but they follow the minority out of fear/need for protection, over a period they become the same to varying extents. Some have personally killed hundreds, others been involved in genocides of hundreds of thousands, many have already organised into mutually antagonistic groups.

I would expect hard core groups to exist around gang leader types right from the start. But their focus would not be on peacefully trying to make a living. They would raid and kill each other in short order until one group had control of all the resources. Then given the demographic it's quite possible no one would survive long term. Or there was a strong ruthless and lucky leader who could pull it all together.

The best chance of survival would be if the prison officers maintained control, bloodshed would still ensue but they may outlast the rest and organise a living if they were ruthless enough.

The Bounty mutiny was ordinary people more or less, and of the core group they all ended up dead except one man who was lucky and ruthless enough to be the last man standing Not because they were short on resources, but because of struggles over ownership and once the killing starts, no one trusts anyone else.

Historically there have been many groups that have ended up settling successfully because they could not go home, some Viking groups for instance. But these were people with a wide range of skills who knew carpentry, metal working, smelting, animal husbandry, how to cultivate land and the advantages of working as a team. In essence these were well educated people in their own terms. Not criminals who know how to sell drugs.

Polynesians did it many times during their expansion, they had the skills already, they could make landfall on an island with no edible vegetation and make a successful colonisation with what they had in their canoes. Due to population size they would start off as extended families or even nuclear families and then as their population rose turn to tribes. But even they had failed attempts where they all died out and times of extreme pressure even at low levels of population in some places.

Comment: The way this answer compares criminals to moral-derived idiots seems to be sincerely unrealistic. Yes, a society made up of criminals will have a harder time, but "raid and kill each other in short order until one group had control of all the resources" seems far from a given. If anything that sounds completely and utterly unlikely to me. Criminals are still humans, they still want to survive, they still know what collaboration is, they still have their set of morals, etc. Yes, a thief might have "concluded" that he was justified in stealing, but that doesn't make him okay with murder or rape.

Comment: The ability (or lack thereof) to set up a functioning society will be far more about access to resources and size of the population.

Comment: @DavidMulder I disagree, and I think you have a naive idea about prisoners. You can have resources all around you, useless if you don't recognise them or know how to utilise them. Criminals in general are parasites, they vast majority cannot be dropped in the wilderness, they have no host to be parasitic on so would end up eating each other. Gangs would take control of any resources by force, your moral thief doesn't stand a chance unless he's ruthless and lucky. Gangs are not producers of resources. Probably even normal urbanised people would struggle for survival without conflict

Comment: You wouldn't have a prison ship full of jaywalkers, it's not minimum security, they would be hardened nutcases, sociopaths, killers, rapists, gangsters, career criminals etc,. they will only cooperate through force, and some of the most dangerous just will not cooperate fullstop. The only thing you can trust at your back in a maximum security prison is a concrete wall.

Comment: Maybe you should try to get an idea about criminals from the real world, rather than from movies. Yes, there are sociopaths (and other mental disorders) that let people lose touch with reality, but that's not most criminals. In real life criminals are people who look and behave like the rest of us, they have remorse and will often enough feel bad about the stuff they do or did. They often feel like it's their only choice or that society has hurt them already so much that they are only making up for it. Movie-style criminals are a whole lot rarer than you think.

Comment: Anyway, my main point is, this question is tagged "[science-based]", so please don't base your answer on fiction. At least the Bounty Mutiny answer is based in real life (though even that one is dubious as that's a strong case of "winner writes history")

Comment: @DavidMulder I am basing my answer on real life, prisoners like any group are socialised within their peer group, the longer they're in the peer group the more they're socialised. Maximum security inmates are a whole different story from others. My part on Vikings is real life, as is the bit on Polynesians, Polynesians in particular have been a particular study of mine as I am one and have more access to material than most.

Comment: This [link](https://www.providr.com/most-dangerous-prisoners-in-the-world/) will give an idea of maximum security inmates, it starts with the US, but in reality the others seem much worse. These are not movies, this is real life. While you might be fine with working with these chaps, I would not even want to sleep in their vicinity and if any looked at me sideways I'd take it as a death threat. Maximum dehumanises both inmates and guards over time. The majority are not so bad, but they follow the minority out of fear/need for protection, over a period they become the same to varying extents

Comment: Unless I missed something, I can't see where it's mentioned that these are hardened, maximum security prisoners. Perhaps in this world, it's a normal, routine prison transport. Maybe in this world serious criminals are executed, so don't need to be transported anywhere. You could perhaps compare it to the convict fleets sent to Australia. Plenty of convicts went on to become normal law abiding citizens.

Comment: @user1751825 I missed the bit where it was a transport ship for traffic offenders... but you're correct, I'm going with the OP wanting a dramatic story rather than some misguided shoplifters though, and I can't see your scenario being more likely. If normal people I'd be more inclined to the Siberia scenario, and those places were hell on Earth (except cold). But you don't need a majority of crazies, there is no escape in some prisons from the minority. And they will group. In both cases the guards retained control, which is integral to my answer for success.

Comment: With luck the crazies will kill each other off in their ruthless pursuit of power, and leave the rest of the moderate prisoners to form some kind of semi-functional tribal society. Even if the psycho types stay alive, they'll presumably want to keep some regular prisoners around as their workforce. Also the readers are going to need to have someone to empathize with. They'll soon lose interest in a story if all the characters are total low-lifes.

Comment: @user1751825 the protagonist is an extremely tough loner, ruthless and mental as heck but in a nice way. Grew up on a farm, orphaned and farm destroyed, joined resistance guerilla forces against the horrid empire, great hero,.flashbacks to his losing wife and kids in a bombing, successful revenge against the corrupt politician who ordered it gets him locked up ....guerilla training beats all comers including corrupt and hated guards.. less insane inmates join him as their leader, eventual patriarch of the good tribe ..... pretty standard stuff.. yet never gets old, look forwards to reading it.

Answer (score 2):

The three generations from modern human society to tribalism after a major population crash are something like:

1. modern people educated in now obsolete specialist subjects trying to learn new/old ways of getting enough to eat. They'll try to educate their children but how much they can do so will depend on how wide, or more likely narrow, their margin of survival is. No leisure time means no education for the coming generation.
2. the children who remember something of the modern world and were somewhat educated in it. They have some obsolete skills and knowledge but mainly learn to live in the new world "catch-as-catch-can" and what little their parents can teach them of the old ways.

These first two generations get to live on capital somewhat, stores, raw materials, and technological artifacts from the ship in this case. In the case of a societal collapse the same but far more of it spread all over the world. The third generation may get some material gain form those resources but they'll have to sweat to make them usable.

3. the first generation raised wholly in the new world order, what the *[Emberverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emberverse_series)* refers to as "Changelings" they learn only the skills needed to survive the new world that their parents have the leisure to hand down.

If the population is small and are subsistence farmers, or worse, in terms of time expenditure per food calorie, then there is no time for leisure, or any education outside the necessaries of survival.

You scenario means there is no generation 2 there are those who crash land and then eventually their children, tribalism is almost guaranteed under those circumstances. If the setting is [sufficiently advanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_assembler) then a high energy density, high technology civilisation can be maintained with very little human effort but otherwise reversion is a certainty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the prospects are pretty bleak. The outcome depends on a few variables:

- the ratio between males and females. An all male or an all female population will become extinct when the last survivor bites the bullet. With an unbalanced population the scarcer half will become a valuable resource resulting in fighting between factions for control of this resource.
- whether the planet on which the ship crashed is capable of sustaining human life; this includes chirality of some amino acids, presence of vitamins and lots of other biochemical factors. If not the population will soon have to resort to cannibalism in order to survive, but this is also no a long term solution as this will cause several debilitating diseases in the long run.
- whether the prison ships carried enough seeds, fungi, yeasts and so on to kick start agriculture. If not, then the best that can be achieved is a hunter/gatherer society, but for this to work the planet must be compatible with human life, see the previous point.
- the make up of the prison population; all criminals or all rebels or a mix of both. There are two natural factions, guards vs. prisoners. Depending on how much weaponry survived the guards may hold out for a while (months, tops), but they are seriously outnumbered by zealous rebels and also by smart criminals with antisocial personality disorders. If there are several of the latter than there will be even more factions, each vying for control of scarce resources (weapons, bits of technology remaining, the other gender)
- how much technology survived the crash. As such it is irreplaceable, the chances of a level of technology remaining that can recreate parts that have been broken are astronomically slim to nil. No medical technology, for instance, means that serious injuries are immediately life threatening and will more often than not result in the death of the individual. Couple this with fighting and it is no rocket science to estimate that the average life expectancy beyond the crash is a few years at best, insufficient to raise a child. The latter includes the transfer of language skills and the fine art of living together in some kind of harmony, even if it is only a permanent truce.

The good news is that, if the planet is capable of sustaining human life, that the population will not go completely feral in generation 0, the survivors of the crash. Generation 0 will quickly devolve to stone age level in a few years. When infighting continues, generation 1 will mostly become feral.

Answer (score 0):

**There is zero chance unfortunately - unless they stay onboard and are 'rescued'.**

The chance of a foreign planet having just the right mix of air (nitrogen, carbon dioxide, oxygen and other gases) for normal breathing by the survivors is not even one-in-a-million.

Oxygen is actually not going to be a common gas to be found - if it is then perhaps the atmosphere has gone through a similar process to that of Earth, ie. a Great Oxygenation Event. But if this was the case then there are alien microbes and photosynthesizing life, which being completely foreign to the prisoners bodies will quickly infect them, or are toxic to them, and die.

The only way they can live is to stay on the ship presuming it's life-support systems are active and will last. The ship might as well be in a vacuum.

Eventually the power systems will die and the ship will lose air and the ability to support the prisoners. How long this will take is up to you - but it is inevitable.